# Script won't work in the background

Tags: bash, shell

I'm making my first steps in Linux and shell scripting. Wrote a small script that should alert me if my laptop's battery is running low.
It works in the foreground but not in the background for some reason. Gives out:

```
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control
```

The script code is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
perc=`upower -i $(upower -e | grep BAT) | grep percentage | cut -c26- | cut -c -2`
state=`upower -i $(upower -e | grep BAT) | grep state | cut -c26-`
while true; do
    while [[ $perc -gt 20 ]]; do
        sleep 300
    done
    while [[ $state = 'discharging' ]]; do
        mplayer /root/scripts/sad.ogg   
        sleep 120
    done
    while [[ $perc -le 20 ]]; do
        sleep 300
    done
done
```

Will greatly appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with mplayer the do connect error is saying that it's truing to get a socket with lirc, it should work if you set your

```
$HOME/.mplayer/config

lirc=no
```

Comment: It helped with the error lines but it still won't play the sound in the background. Only if I keep it in the foreground.

Comment: Well you were right. Problem was indeed in mplayer. Turns out it doesn't play in the background. At least on Debian and Gentoo. Thank you for your help!